# Does assigning an instance of class A to member of class A a cyclic reference?

Tags: python, cyclic-reference

```
class Yummie(object):
    instance = None
Yummie.instance = Yummie()
```

Since `Yummie.instance` is an instance of `Yummie` and `type(Yummie.instance) == Yummie` is true, would that be an example of a cyclic reference? Should I prefer to create a weak reference instead? With weak references though,  it will also need another place for the `Yummie` instance to live, otherwise it would instantly be deleted again.

Comment: No, this isn't a circular reference. The *class* `Yummie` has an attribute that references a single instance of `Yummie`. That's all.

Comment: @Asad But the `Yummie` instance has a reference to its class, no?

Comment: Yes, I neglected that (Ignacio's answer points this out). I was thinking more in terms of program correctness than memory usage, where circular references prevent the evaluation of interdependent methods/objects because each needs the other to be evaluated first. That isn't the case here, since the `Yummie` class can be defined without needing the instance of `Yummie` to exist.

Comment: If you had `instance = Yummie()`, that would be a circular reference, since the class `Yummie` can't be defined without an instance of `Yummie`, and an instance of `Yummie` can't be created without the class `Yummie` being defined. That wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a cyclic reference in that `Yummie().__class__` contains `Yummie`, but unless you're running a very old version of Python this shouldn't be a problem due to the garbage collector's cycle detection.